# Load an application with C# and verify that application has loaded completely

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a query related to application process start. Here is what I want to do.

**Pre-work**

Load a pdf file using adobe reader in C# application

**Actual problem**

I want to note following time of adobe pdf reader. How much time is consumed,

- In executing adobe pdf reader application
- In opening sample in adobe pdf reader.

When we kill adobe process how much time is used in,

- Terminating adobe pdf reader application

I am stuck because I am unable to compute these times in c sharp application. Why?

- I am unable to verify that application is loaded completely or not
- I am unable to verify that pdf sample loaded all it's components inside pdf reader

**Code I had implemented yet**

```
double _time = 0;

try
{               
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();    
    Process myProcess = new Process();    
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName  = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"; //not the full application path
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "D:\\Sample.pdf";
    myProcess.Start();
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    if (myProcess.HasExited == false)
    {
       stopwatch.Start();
       /* 
       *  1. Giving time to application to load, 
       *  2. Load sample 
       */
       myProcess.WaitForExit(1000);
       // Calculate time 
       _time=_time+stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
       /*
       * Give extra time in case if application need more time
       */
       myProcess.WaitForExit(1500);
    }
    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;                   
    myProcess.Kill();                
}
catch(Exception exp){
   Console.WriteLine("Error "+exp.Message+".  "+exp+"   "+ exp.Source);
}

Console.WriteLine("PDF opened in  (time) : "+TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_time).TotalMinutes);
Console.WriteLine("Total PDF reader Life cycle : "+stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

If someone help me in this way using c sharp / vb.net code

- Pdf reader loaded complete  (time)
- Verify application is loaded completely
- Sample loaded pdf reader (time)
- Pdf reader killed (time )

Thanks,

Comment: For what reason are you measuring that time? I could think what Adobe has API to manipulate their products, you have to use it if you want things like when application is loaded, when file is loaded, etc.

Comment: I want to monitor the application time execution. I want to optimize the application more so that I can make application to run fast (this is the goal) but now I want to check how much time is consumed in whole process.

Comment: *optimize the application more* - you can't optimize how external application will behave, nor you should.

Comment: this is something else, related to memory and other aspects, I just want to know If someone can guide me how to grab an (in this case adobe reader) application start, load sample, execution time and termination time through C#. 
If someone can.